# line integral Parametrization Problem

Tags: line-integrals

I am stuck with this question from my assignment based on line integral-

[image]

What I don't understand here is that given c(t), I can directly plug in values of x, y and z (respectively cost, sint and t/2π) and solve the integral for 0 < t < 2π but than what is the significance of joining (1 0 0) to (1 0 1) or is it like since line integral is independent of path joining the end points, answer in both cases will be equal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does the questioner mean that you should add a straight line to the path to make it closed?

Comment: nopes, the question is complete in this way only.

Comment: then the only significance of the "join" is that that's the start and end of the path - your method seems fine in which case

Comment: and the integrals will only be path-independent if the $\nabla\times F=0$

Answer (score 2):

The grammatical subject of "joining" is the path, not you. That is, the problem isn't asking *you* to join those two points (e.g. by a straight line segment), it's merely describing the path as a path joining those two points. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to show the line integrals' curve is equal to zero, therefore it is irrotational. 
After that you know the vector $F$ is conservative and thus the line integral $F.dr= U(x_2,y_2,z_2)-U(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ which are the endpoints given to you.